# Refining the type of a tagged union

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a function that will return a value of a tagged union, but I want the return type to be refined depending on the tag. For example,

```
type Token = {kind: "+"} | {kind: "var", text: string};

let tokens: Token[] = [{kind: "var", text: "x"}, {kind: "+"}, {kind: "var", text: "y"}];

function pullToken<Kind extends Token["kind"]>(kind: Kind): Extract<Token, {kind: Kind}> {
    let token = tokens.shift();
    if (typeof token === "undefined" || token.kind !== kind) {
        throw "oops";
    }
    return token;
}

let token = pullToken("var");
console.log(token.text);
```

gives me the following error

```
TS2322: Type 'Token' is not assignable to type 'Extract<{ kind: "+"; }, { kind: Kind; }> | Extract<{ kind: "var"; text: string; }, { kind: Kind; }>'.
  Type '{ kind: "+"; }' is not assignable to type 'Extract<{ kind: "+"; }, { kind: Kind; }> | Extract<{ kind: "var"; text: string; }, { kind: Kind; }>'.
    Type '{ kind: "+"; }' is not assignable to type 'Extract<{ kind: "var"; text: string; }, { kind: Kind; }>'.
```

I expected `token` to be refined by the condition in the `if` statement, but it isn't. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a known issue in TypeScript that you cannot use control flow analysis to narrow generic type parameters (see [microsoft/TypeScript#24085](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24085)) or values whose type depend on generic type parameters (see [microsoft/TypeScript#13995](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13995)).

Generally if you have a value of a union type (like `Token`) and perform a type guard on it, then the compiler will use [control flow analysis](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/8010) to narrow the apparent type of that value to some member or members of the original union (like `{kind: "var", text: string}`).  That's all well and good when the value is of a non-generic type.

But if your value (like `token`) is of a type that depends on a generic type parameter constrained to a union (like `Kind extends Token`) then *this does not happen*.  It does not narrow the type of the value, and it *definitely* does not narrow the type parameter (like `Kind`) itself.

It's a tough problem to address, since in many cases it would not be correct for the compiler to narrow the type parameter, and even where it might be correct, it would require that the compiler spend more time performing some higher-order type analysis.  Maybe eventually the language will allow your code to just "work".  For now, you need to work around it.

---

The compiler is unable to verify that `token` is of the type `Extract<Token, {kind: Kind}>`.  But you have written code which should (I hope) make that true.  Since you know something the compiler doesn't about the type of `token`, you can use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to just tell it so:

```
return token as Extract<Token, {kind: Kind}>;
```

That will silence the error.  Note that the burden of verifying type safety inside the implementation of `pullToken()` is now on you; if you make a mistake or lie (e.g., `return {kind: "+"} as Extract<Token, {kind: Kind}>;` the compiler will not catch it.  So  be careful.

---

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKg9gawgOygXigbygglsgEwC4oAiAalKgF8oAfLHfYsgNwEMAnUgGimAgAPYCQDOwTvgDmNANwAoeQBsIwfohSiS8JMgDaAXXRQ92PIRKkO3PgOGXBVanzPNLlGi6YW2XXvyERMhAnAwV5ADMAV2QAY2BcOFQwKKUlHRQAHgBpZihAlAJRWA19UnMCUgMAPgAKCpJcwgBKEgBRYU52eMyM5C8GqCaCGmqseSgoFTVgUuNZ3VEAOlEAC1wI4FrmhUmNqFrQSDgI9V10NAxSGIIICPwISvoGBZQliqgAQkvvAmbxyaTYCrThwADuZDgcDAolIuxoEygnFUUU4qFeqHYxQ6Em6wF6pQGbiGeWo1QU1EUKTSfVqAFl2MCll1CHAALbbKCZKAABiWAFYoAB+MgeSzWUg7RTTM4oYzU9KlWpWPxS2JJURwFRLJRwKSHUpLOzAHZQIA)